# asp.net connecting to a 64 bit oracle client

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I need to connect to a oracle database on another server so I don't have acces to the database itself.

I created an application in c# with winforms and I was able use this database when I changed some settings in the build options.

Now I am translating the application into a asp.net website and I got this error:

**'Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.'**

This is the same error as what I received when I used winforms but then It was possible to fix it in the build options.

Is it possible to fix this error without having acces to the server where the database is stored?

Comment: Which type of DB server installed? 64-bit mode or 32-bit mode? And what type of your client?

Comment: @Khazratbek The type of DB server makes no difference.

Comment: @mason The type of DB server makes no difference, but types of server and client makes difference, that's why I asked both of them

Comment: @Khazratbek No. That does not matter. 32 bit client can talk to 64 bit server, and 64bit client can talk to 32 bit server. The only thing that matters is that if your application is compiled for 32 bit, you must use the 32 bit client. And if your application is compiled for 64 bit, you must use the 64 bit client. Or use the [driver written in managed code](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) that works with 32 bit or 64 bit applications and avoid the whole problem.

Comment: I installed the 32 bit oracle client, everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the database server version. It's the version of the client components/Oracle driver that you have installed on the web server and whether your web app is running in 32/64 bit mode. You need to make sure they are consistent (ie 32 bit app uses 32 bit driver, 64 bit app use 64 bit driver). Check the Enable 32-bit applications setting in your IIS app pool advanced settings.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find the IIS app pool advanced settings?

Comment: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx

Comment: I noticed that I hadn't installed IIS, now I did this but I can't see the website  I am working on in that list.

Comment: Oh you are still running this locally in Visual Studio then? What version of Visual Studio are you running? Actually scrap that if all you are interested is getting it working. You can actually install oracle client 32 and 64 bit drivers side by side on the same machine. Then it doesn't matter if your app run in 32 or 64 bit mode.

http://realfiction.net/2009/11/26/Use-32-and-64bit-Oracle-Client-in-parallel-on-Windows-7-64-bit-for-eg-NET-Apps/

Comment: Thanks, just installed the 32 bit client and it works now.